# router changed but component does not rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm using react-router v4 and redux. I have a react-router event like so

```
//src/App/components/common/Notifications
onCommentClick = (id) => {
    this.props.history.push(`/dashboard/${id}`)
}
```

It will change the browser url, my route is setup correctly I guess

```
//src/App/containers/dashboard/user/NotificationDetail
renderUserRoute() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={UserAreaGuarded} />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard/:id" component={NotificationDetail} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
```

but the problem is redux doesn't seem to rerender my container component, I need to refresh to get the right content.

I created a repo just to demo this issue https://github.com/thian4/hoc-redux, been stuck for so long for this, couldn't find any clue why it doesn't rerender.

Comment: As far as I know you will need to use `shouldCompomentUpdate` as React is only doing a shallow check of the props so it thinks nothing has changed. You will see that `props.location.pathname` will change on each route change, so you can use that to force re-render.

Comment: Did you try pushing the state along with the path ? `history.push(path, reduxState)`

Comment: Redux shouldn't be in play here as React-Router will handle the updates based on history changes. My guess is that the Switch component may be causing this. As your Route paths are not ambiguous, try removing Switch. Prefer a codesandbox example over github repo link if possible, it makes experimentation easier.

Comment: @ChrisR why push the reduxState? where does it come from?

Comment: @hazardous somehow codesandbox can't read my repo. Switch as I know is needed to render 1 component, there's a reason why it's there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with the router, the [`NotificationDetail`](https://github.com/thian4/hoc-redux/blob/master/src/App/containers/dashboard/user/NotificationDetail.js) component invokes `fetchNotification` only in [`componentDidMount`](https://github.com/thian4/hoc-redux/blob/master/src/App/containers/dashboard/user/NotificationDetail.js#L11,#L12). As you are [rendering the route components with the `Route` `component` prop](https://github.com/thian4/hoc-redux/blob/master/src/App/containers/dashboard/index.js#L30), the `NotificationDetail` route component is mounted only once and then merely updated on every re-render.

There are two ways to fix this...

1. In `NotificationDetail`, do the `fetchNotification` stuff in `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentdidMount`, simply rename the method. This approach is better.
2. Use a stateless component as the value of `component` prop in `dashboard\index.js`:

   ```
   renderUserRoute() {
     return (
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={UserAreaGuarded} />
         <Route exact 
             path="/dashboard/:id" 
             component={props => <NotificationDetail {...props} />} />
       </Switch>
     )
   }
   ```

   This will make React-Router render a new route component every time the route changes. Obviously this has performance issues over #1.

Unrelated to this, please add a `key={i}` on [this line](https://github.com/thian4/hoc-redux/blob/master/src/App/components/common/Notifications.js#L60) in `Notification.js` to fix the dreaded `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.` warning.

Hope this helps.